# Get the SNMP request message using adventnet/WebNMS in hex format

Tags: java, snmp

I am using WebNMS/adventnet to get and set SNMP command on a device.

I would like to access programmatically the request and response data that is printed in hex format when debug mode is on.

```
import com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.SnmpAPI;
import com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.SnmpException;
import com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.SnmpOID;
import com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.SnmpPDU;
import com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.SnmpSession;
import com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.UDPProtocolOptions;

public class SNMPWebNMS {
 //Need both request and response in hex format
 //It prints in log , request and response data in hex format   
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SnmpException {

    SnmpAPI api=new SnmpAPI();
    api.setDebug(true);
    SnmpSession session=new SnmpSession(api);
    session.open();
    SnmpPDU pdu=new SnmpPDU();
    UDPProtocolOptions options=new UDPProtocolOptions("192.168.0.1");
    pdu.setProtocolOptions(options);
    pdu.setCommunity("dummy");
    pdu.setCommand(SnmpAPI.GET_REQ_MSG);
    SnmpOID oid=new SnmpOID(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
    pdu.addNull(oid);       
    SnmpPDU result=session.syncSend(pdu);
    System.out.println("result = "+result.toString());
    session.close();
   }

 }
```

Comment: I suggest you add add examples e.g. a toString() result for, say, the ResponseEvent that you tried,  and the debug logging you want ?

Comment: Hi,
Please find the code inline to the questions.When I do tostring() to the result, it prints the object of the result.Could you explain a bit?

Comment: Perhaps add an example of how you want the output to look?

Comment: I need the inform SNMP request constructed using WEBNMS before sending onto to the device.I am able to get the request using wireshark.I need to get it programmatically.Hex Format separated by : is 
30:28:02:01:01:04:08:61:65:72:6f:68:69:76:65:a0:19:02:01:01:02:01:00:02:01:00:30:0e:30:0c:06:08:2b:06:01:02:01:01:01:00:05:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this instruction:

```
result.getVariableBindings().toString();
```

To get a string value of OID.